# sbt Error: Error occurred during initialization of VM. Multiple Garbage Collectors selected

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, sbt

While executing sbt command on a project I am getting the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Multiple garbage collectors selected
```

I have also included the below in my .profile file for Ubuntu (20.04)

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx4G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=4G -Xss1M -Duser.timezone=GMT"
```

What should be done to start the sbt shell?

Comment: It was an error because of java version. For all projects I was using openjdk-11 but this particular project required using openjdk-14. As soon as I installed openjdk-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error because of java version. For all projects, till now, I was using openjdk-11 and everything was working fine but this particular project **required using openjdk-14**. As soon as I installed openjdk-14 it started working fine.